# Prove that $\exists\ b \in (0,9)$ such that $\int_{0}^{b}\frac{x+x^{\frac{1}{7}}-4}{9-x}\,dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How do you solve this kind of problem?

> Prove that $\exists\ b \in (0,9)$ s.t.
>   $$\int_{0}^{b}\frac{x+x^{\frac{1}{7}}-4}{9-x}\,dx = 0.$$

I tried to study the function defined by the integral looking for some symmetries but that path has not been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, considering the integral function:
$$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x+x^{\frac{1}{7}}-4}{9-x}\,dx$$
is a good start. Now show that:

1) $F$ is continuous in $[0,9)$,

2) $\exists t_1\in (0,1)$ such that $F(t_1)<0$,

3) $\exists t_2\in (8,9)$ such that $F(t_2)>0$,

4) apply the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to $F$ with respect to the interval $[t_1,t_2]$.

Comment: Thank you, my intuition was right :)